# Google Vertex AI AutoML - cannot specify schema for CSV Dataset

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have created Tabular datasets in Vertex AI / Datasets based on some CSV files. However when I try to use these datasets in AutoML for training and prediction, there is no way to specify the data types of the fields. In [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/data-types-tabular#csv) I could not find how to do the "transformations". In theory it supports the following types:

- Text
- Categorical
- Numeric
- Timestamp

In case of BigQuery tables it is pretty obvious to get the data types as it is explicitely specified by the schema of the table. However in case of a CSV file sometimes it is not obvious to find out the type of a field and indeed in my case sometimes AutoML guesses incorrectly. Any ideas how to specify the data types explicitely for CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud Python SDK for Vertex AI does not support transformation of column data types. Currently it can be done only through the Cloud Console.

Once the data is imported in Vertex AI datasets and when the training pipeline is created, it automatically detects and analyses the provided CSV file and gives information about various data types as shown in the image below. The transformations of data types occur after the data is imported.

If Vertex AI identifies the data type incorrectly, we can use the drop down menu to change it to the desired data type as shown in the below image. Please refer to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNWCzyCK4Us) for a demo on building and training models with Vertex AI.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick reply. Actually you are talking about a new feature of AutoML / Vertex AI - AutoML Tables. I was talking about the older method: importing CSV file to Vertex AI using the original Datasets's API. I don't want to import anything by hand, I would like to see some python code in the documentation on how to do the transformation. This AutoML Tables does not yet available in all of my projects (in one of my projects I had to manually enable this API). And AutoML Tables is still not part of the UI of the Vertex AI...